# Regex pattern for enclosed by string?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have follwing script and the script outputs a array like below.

````
[
    [0] "# bash LAN\n\n```\nnmap -sn 192.168.3.*\n```\n",
    [1] "# node.js npm\n\n`sudo apt update && sudo apt install nodejs npm -y`\n",
    [2] "# something title\n\nsomething content\n",
    [3] "# bash log\n\n```\ntail -f",
    [4] "# or",
    [5] "# tail -f -n 50\n```\n\n\n"
]
````

````
Encoding.default_external = 'UTF-8'

require 'pry'
require "awesome_print"

# p \
ap \
arrayobj = <<-'EOS'.scan(/^#(?!#).*(?:\R(?!#(?!#)).*)*/) # .scan(/^#.*$\n(.*)/m)


# bash LAN

\```
nmap -sn 192.168.3.*
\```

# node.js npm

`sudo apt update && sudo apt install nodejs npm -y`

# something title

something content

# bash log

\```
tail -f
# or
# tail -f -n 50
\```


EOS
````

I'd like to split the EOS-enclosed text by `#`(single hash) but if the single hash is enclosed by Markdown code tag, ignore that single hash.

So, in that case, what I wanted is following output. How do you get the output?

````
[
    [0] "# bash LAN\n\n```\nnmap -sn 192.168.3.*\n```\n",
    [1] "# node.js npm\n\n`sudo apt update && sudo apt install nodejs npm -y`\n",
    [2] "# something title\n\nsomething content\n",
    [3] "# bash log\n\n```\ntail -f\n# or\n# tail -f -n 50\n```\n\n\n",
]
````

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23589221/5961578

Comment: Probably best to do it line by line and turn a flag on/off when encountering a ``` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

````
.scan(/^#(?!#)(?:(?!```)[^#]|```.*?```)*/m).flatten
````

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/3xA3gE) and a [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/KRexfNKV58ltxy).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `#(?!#)` - a `#` not followed with another `#`
- ```` (?:(?!```)[^#]|```.*?```)* ```` - 0 or more repetitions of

  - ```` (?!```)[^#] ```` - any char other than `#` that does not start a ```` ``` ```` char sequence
  - `|` - or
  - ```` ``` ```` - three backticks
  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
  - ```` ``` ```` - three backticks

The `m` modifier makes `.` match any char including line break chars.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in this case is maybe not completely standard, but here you are:

1. Split the string on triple quotes:

   ````
   .split('```')
   ````
2. Take the pieces in pairs. First piece is normal markdown, second is code snippet.

   ```
   .each_slice(2)
   ```
3. Add markers before `#` in the first piece, not in the second. Notice that the MD piece is nil in the last slice.

   ```
   .map { |txt, code = nil| [txt.gsub('#', "\x00#"), code].compact }
   ```
4. Join back

   ````
   .flatten.join('```')
   ````
5. Split by marker

   ```
   .split("\x00")
   ```

The byte '0' is not expected to be in your text, if you have it, just use another marker, like a long random string *without any `#`* that you generate when starting the process.